# Qgis how to distribute points inside a polygon

Tags: qgis

I´m new to QGIS, lately I got 2 Shapefiles one showing the polygons for some areas that represent street blocks, and another shapefile with the points that represent the number of comercial stores in the area, so sometimes we have one and others we have 90, depending on which street the survey was done.
The problem is that the points layer shows only one point where there should be more than one, that is because all points corresponding to a certain street or block are asigned the centroid of that polygon as coordinates. Is there a way to distribute all points automatically inside the polygons so if there is only one the points stays in the centroid and if there are more the points shift position in order to show how many points are exactly? Added a screencap for references

Comment: Could you provide the relevant part of the code related to what you have already tried? And your screenshot didn't come in your question.

Comment: Ask in [Geographic Information Systems](http://gis.stackexchange.com). This question is off-topic here.

Comment: not exactly what you ask for, but it might be a lead http://north-road.com/2016/09/06/point-cluster-renderer-crowdfunding-successful/